# Set layout_anchor at runtime on FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library, android-coordinatorlayout, android-support-design

I am trying to animate a android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton that is pinned to my AppBarLayout. I can set it fine within the layout xml and it shows up fine. However i am doing a Shared Element Transition to this layout and the FAB is showing up before the view is set. I tried to set the visibility to GONE and INVISIBLE but they seem to be disregarded if the layout_anchor is set in the layout xml. Is there anyway around this?

I would like the activity to load with the shared element transition then fade in my FAB. I just can't hide the FAB on load. I could do it without using the layout_anchor but prefer to keep that if possible.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you have a FAB with the the `app:layout_anchor` attribute, and you want to set the visibility you should use something like this:

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) fab.getLayoutParams();
params.setAnchorId(View.NO_ID);
fab.setLayoutParams(params);
fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

If you want to set the`app:layout_anchor` dinamically you can use the same code:

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams p = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) fab.getLayoutParams();
p.setAnchorId(xxxx);
fab.setLayoutParams(p);
```

Comment: This looks very promising. What about setting the layout_anchorGravity in this way?

Comment: I can leave the layout_anchorGravity in the layout xml and just set the anchor id like you said above. This is great! Thanks

Comment: This does work for setting the anchor dynamically, it however does not solve the shared element transition problem mentioned [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31804170/android-shared-element-transition-between-two-activities-does-not-work). Setting the anchor is what seems to bork the animation. Without setting any anchor, the animations seem to work fine.

Comment: This does nothing if I set it after adding the view and crashes if I set it before adding the view...