# Android shared element transition between two activities does not work

Tags: android, android-design-library, floating-action-button

In my app I'm trying to use the newly introduced element sharing between activities. Everything works like a charm if the shared element is with fixed position (e.g. `android:layout_gravity="top"`) but the problem comes when the view is anchored.

My first activity looks like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:auto="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        ...
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/play_all"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My second activity looks like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:auto="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_play"
        auto:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
        android:transitionName="fab_button"
        auto:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="192dp">
        ...
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    ...

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The code I use is as follows:

```
Intent intent = ...;
ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, view, "fab_button");
startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

If I use the `layout_anchor` and `layout_anchorGravity` attributes the transition between the two FABs is done with no animation. If the second FAB is with fixed position, it works perfectly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you are not doing anything wrong. My app is very very similar to yours for these two activities, and I have the same problem. I think that shared element transition framework can't get the position of the anchored element… I hope someone can find a solution though

Comment: I see that there are applications where this behavior works well. I guess they are doing some custom logic for achieving this effect.

Comment: Thank you for your report, been scratching my head for hours against this. As I've removed the app:layout_anchor the transition was smooth as it needed to be. How is it possible this matter was so hard to discover and hasn't been reported yet... Come on..

Comment: You should report this bug in [android's bug tracker](http://b.android.com) under Support Libs

Answer (score 16):

This might be a bit late, but I found a way around the issue. You have to wrap your shared element into a layout, and put the anchor on that layout:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        auto:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
        auto:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/play"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_play"
            android:transitionName="fab_button" />

<FrameLayout/>
```

Comment: Is it a bug in coordinatorLayout + shared transitions? 
But it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Activity Shared Elements Transitions:

Follow the steps.

1. [Enable Window Content Transitions](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition#1-enable-window-content-transitions)
2. [Assign a Common Transition Name](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition#2-assign-a-common-transition-name)
3. [Start Activity](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition#3-start-activity)
4. [Multiple Shared Elements](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition#4-multiple-shared-elements)
5. [Customizing Shared Elements Transition](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition#5-customizing-shared-elements-transition)

I think you do not have follow the second step. You had given `android:transitionName="fab_button"` in Second `Activity` but not given in First `Activity`.

`XML` of First `Activity` (added `android:transitionName="fab_button"`):

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

        android:transitionName="fab_button"

        android:id="@+id/play_all"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"/>
```

May above links will helps you.

Comment: Nope, that's not it. The first activity view is an imageview and the destination is an anchored FAB. If I make the destination FAB non-anchored everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should have transition name in receiving activity also. Check my code.

**First Activity**

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_register"
        android:transitionName="@string/transition"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**And Second Activity xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:transitionName="@string/transition"
tools:context="com.example.shoppingappdemo.RegiserActivity">
```

Comment: Same what i have given in my answer.

Comment: Sorry for that..actually my net was slow so after i have posted my answer i show urs...sorry for that

Comment: That's not the issue. Please read the question, everything works fine if the destination FAB is un-anchored. The problem seems to be when the destination FAB is anchored.